# What game is this? 8x8 wooden grid with 2 sets of 9 marbles

Tags: identify-this-game

Anyone got any idea what this game is? A wooden board consisting of 8x8 grids of holes and 2 sets of 9 marbles (blue and green, all marbles in a set appear to be the same).

The label says ‘Oriental Chess’ by Lagoon Games but it’s not oriental chess from what I have found.

[image]

Comment: If its comes with a label calling it 'Oriental Chess'  you might not get a much better answer.  Googling that name and publisher it sounds like it should have come with a set of rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oriental Chess by Lagoon Games

It looks like it is an old game no longer in production.
Here's a couple of pictures of the rules.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent - thanks very much. Although the game was bought new (from where I can't remember), I never had the instructions.

Comment: No problem, I hope you have a good time playing it.

Comment: Im now inspired to try and write an iPhone version, as it *seems* fairly straightforward...

Comment: That's nice, send me the link when you are done.

Comment: Might be a while!

Comment: I noticed several ambiguities in the rules. 1. It is possible to capture along two perpendicular lines. 2. If a capture along a single line is both an enclosure and a fill, how is this resolved? Proposal: "you capture only the enclosed pieces". [This gives the variant "you capture as if filled".] 3. The win condition does not include the possibility of total elimination. Does it mean you can only win by keeping one opponent's piece on the board? Silly. 4. If you're reduced to one piece, can you win by eliminating all opponent's pieces? (See 3.) 5. Alt win: your opponent can't move. Thoughts?

Comment: @Ola. Since both copies of the rules are obviously different, were these issued with different versions of the game? How did you get a hold of them? (Just curious if you have the game as well.)